# VBA To subtract today's date from a date in another column and return a number

Tags: vba, excel, date, subtraction

I hope you can help. I have a small piece of code below.  The issue I am having is that I am trying to subtract today's date from the date in Column C (see Pic 1) and then return a numerical result in Column D and then continue this formula down Column D until there is no values left in column C to subtract against.

So today's date is 09/03/2017 I want to subtract this date from the date in C2 03/07/2017 giving me 2 in D2 and then continue this through column D until C has a blank cell.

The piece of code that is bugging is `Range("D2").Formula = DateDiff(C2, Date, "d")`

The error I get is run time error 13 type mismatch.

The larger piece of code it belongs to is

```
Public Sub Activate_Sheet()



Worksheets("In Progress").Activate
Columns.AutoFit
Range("N:N").EntireColumn.Delete
Range("D1").Value = "# days open"
Range("D2").Formula = DateDiff(C2, Date, "d")

End Sub
```

As always any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Pic 1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateDiff` function Parameters:

- *Interval* in your case "d" (represnting days), is the first parameter, not the third.

You can't use `C2` inside the `DateDiff` function, but you need to get the value from that cell by using `Range("C2").Value`.

Also, `DateDiff` will return a Numeric result in days, so you need to enter it in `Range("D2").Value` and not `Formula`.

Modify your code to:

```
Range("D2").Value = DateDiff("d", Range("C2").Value , Date)
```

**Edit 1**: To run this code for all occupied cells in Column C:

```
Dim LastRow  As Long, i As Long
With Worksheets("In Progress")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        .Range("D" & i).Value = DateDiff("d", .Range("C" & i).Value, Date)
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Just a word of caution. The values (no of days) will be based on the date of you executing this macro.  Incase you want the values (no of days) to represent the current date, whenever you open the file use answer by Peh.

Comment: Hi to all involved in this answer and thank you all for the help. It is greatly appreciated. I have gone with `Range("D2").Value = DateDiff("d", Range("C2").Value , Date)`as I need the value to remain static for that day. Thank you Shai Rado. Can i just ask now how I would be able to get this to calculate all the way down the D column? Can anyone advise?

Comment: Shai Rado. Thank you so much for the help, This is beautiful work. Much respect from Dublin. I hope you have a great day. :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
Range("D2").Formula = DateDiff(C2, Date, "d")
```

use

```
Range("D2").Formula = "=DAYS(TODAY(),C7)"
```

`.Formula` has to be a formula as you write it into a cell (for english Excel versions). If you have a non-english (localized) Excel version then you can use `.FormulaLocal` to write formulas in your localized language.

Comment: Just a word of caution.  This formula will keep updating and hence the values (no of days) will be different if you open the file tomorrow.  Incase you want the same value to remain use answer by Shai Rado.

Comment: @TheKing You are totally right the 2 answers do not have the same result. This was my intention because Column D is named `# days open` and he tried to use `.formula` so I highly assumed that he wants that column to show how many days the issues are open from today.